# Set a cookie in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, cookies

How can I set a cookie when a background color is changed? I created a basic switcher which  changes the body color, but I want to save the changed color in a cookie.

Any Idea?

jQuery code:

```
    $('.first li').click(function(){
        var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
       $('body').css('background','url('+src+')');
     });
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/5HV28/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add the following plugin to your page: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Now you can do the following:

Create cookie:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

Read cookie:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie');
```

Comment: Adding a library to your project to do one thing? Bit of a sledgehammer approach...

Comment: @RichardA - Not *one* thing. I suspect he'll also want to read the cookie later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an HTML5 localStorage and will works

```
    window.localStorage.setItem("color_fondo",color);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor =  color;
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert this line at the end of your function.

```
document.cookie = 'userColor="' + document.body.style.background + '"';
```

Comment: This has the benefit of working with images, filters, you name it ;)